# How to make a special "or" environment?

Tags: environments

I would like to create an environment that would be made of a vertical line on the left and an automatic "or" inserted at each linebreak. Its purpose would be in a maths context.

It would look like this :

[image: model]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of a classmate, I was able to make a new solution which looks even more like what I originally wanted. It uses a command instead of an environment but it's much better!

Here is the code:

```latex
\newcounter{orcounter}

\newenvironment{orlist}
{
\begin{array}{|l}
\setcounter{orcounter}{0}
}
{
\end{array}
}

\newcommand{\oritem}[1]{%
\ifthenelse{\theorcounter<1}{}{\\ \text{ou} \\}#1\stepcounter{orcounter}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\orenv}{>{\SplitList{\\}}m}{%
\begin{orlist}\ProcessList{#1}{\oritem}\end{orlist}}
```

One can use it very simply as follows:

```latex
\[\orenv{G\text{ abélien} \\ I=\ensvide}\]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `tcolorbox` package to create a environment which create a vertical line.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
% \usepackage{pgfplots}


\newtcolorbox{env}{
        enhanced,
        breakable, % This make the box breakable
        boxrule=0pt,
        frame hidden,
        borderline west={2pt}{0pt}{black}, % this create the line
        colback=white, % The background color,
        math upper,
        hbox,
        center
    }

\begin{document}
 Text text text
    \begin{env}
        \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\delta(x-a)dx = f(a)
    \end{env}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to make it work inside maths delimiters (ie `\[\]` in my case)?

Comment: You can use ```\begin{env} \[ Lalalala \] \end{env}```, I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: I would like to be able to use it like I would use the `cases` environment: inside the maths delimiters

Comment: Try add these options inside the ```newtcolorbox```: math upper,
            hbox,
            center

Comment: it doen't work at all. I just get tons of errors

Comment: I edit the post

Comment: It is not really what I wanted neither. I found a solution on my own. I'm gonna post it as an answer and accept it. Thanks for your help anyways.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a array~like environnement and add the **or** before every element that isn't the first, not very  clean but it works.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}

    \usepackage{ifthen}
    \newcounter{orcounter}

    \newenvironment{orlist}{%
      \noindent\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{|l}
      \setcounter{orcounter}{0}
    }{%
     \end{tabular*}
    }

    \newcommand{\oritem}[1]{%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\theorcounter}{0}}{\hspace{-1em}}{\\ \textbf{or}\\}
      #1\stepcounter{orcounter}
    }

    % -- Usage Example
    \begin{document}

    \begin{orlist}
      \oritem{example 1}
      \oritem{example 2}
    \end{orlist}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you extend your code into a compilable example please to improve it, starting with `\documentclass{}` and ending with `\end{document}`, just helps future readers if the code works straight away `:)`

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution on my own :

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\newenvironment{ouenv}
{\left\lvert\begin{array}{l}}
{\end{array}\right.}

\begin{document}
\[\begin{ouenv}G\text{ abélien} \\ \text{ou} \\ I=\ensvide\end{ouenv}\]
\end{document}
```

It gives the following result :

[image: result]

(Text is in French but it doesn't matter)